# How to adjust image size in html using css

Tags: html, css

I'm developping an ionic application, and i want to display some images in some cards, the problem is that my images have not the some size, and i want them to look the some.

The idea is to use à css class that will solve the problem ( at least in the width )

```
.full-width-image {
width: 100%
}
```

this class will solve the problem of size and all the images will have the some width. how ever i dont know how to make a fixed height for them all. if i add to my css class a fixed height like:

```
.full-width-image {
width: 100%;
height: 60px; 
}
```

some pictures will look ugly:
[how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdpqR.png)

what i want is to hide the extra part of the image.

Comment: Show code please. We need it to help you.

Comment: Set a fixed height on the image container and set it to : `overflow-hidden`

Comment: `.full-width-image {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px; 
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a set width and height you can use `object-fit: cover;` for the image to fill the entire space without losing its aspect ratio.

Comment: Thanks alot, i tried this and i got what i wanted! thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use a flex wrapper around an image.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px gray;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em;
}

.wrapper img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.example {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.png?v=9c558ec15d8a">
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg">
</div>

<div>
```

Using this technique you get a kind of smart image - it scales itself to fit your wrapper, its fixed size, but without distortion. Look, there are black borders around the images, so you can see that both an image with width > height and an image with a tree, where height > width, fit well the wrapper, restricting the width and the height correspondingly.

Also you can you `inline-flex` instead of `flex` in the wrapper class.